# Ethernet throughput anomalies

Tags: tcp, udp, throughput

I have run into a few weird blips testing a throughput program. It seems to work fine and is sending messages over a 1Gbps cable. The program works between two computers one side being the master and the other being the slave. The master sends a message to the slave (of size 1,10,100,1000 words chosen by the user) which is then echoed back. This process is repeated for usually about 10,000 messages. The transmission can happen over TCP or UDP again chosen by the user.

What is strange is when multiple instances are run between the same computers, but going to different ports, the total test time actually shrinks, and I can not seem to understand why. I thought that maybe TCP was doing some sort of optimization for larger packets but

a) they are going to and from different ports
b) the same thing happens with UDP

So why would multiple instances actually lower the total transmission time for each individual test?

Comment: A wild guess: there's some buffering going on somewhere inbetween, and the buffers fill up faster when you're running multiple instances.

Comment: I start 5 different executables with a batch file though and they go to and from different ports, so I dunno how they would affect each other besides if that buffering were going on somewhere over the line?